# Memory Allocation with P/Invoke (System.AccessViolationException)

Tags: c#, winapi, 64-bit

I'm trying to compile the following [C# code](https://pastebin.com/NU0tc64H) to X64 bit by using LookupPrivilegeName to resolve memory addresses to permissions.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
public class Program
{

    //Open Process Token Starts Here

    public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
    public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
    public const UInt32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
                TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
                TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
                TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, UInt32 DesiredAccess, ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

    //Open Prcoess Token Ends Here
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID
    {
        public uint LowPart;
        public uint HighPart;
    }
    public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        public int PrivilegeCount;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
        public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }
    //Token Privileges



    //GetTokenInformation Starts Here


    enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
    {
        TokenUser = 1,
        TokenGroups,
        TokenPrivileges,
        TokenOwner,
        TokenPrimaryGroup,
        TokenDefaultDacl,
        TokenSource,
        TokenType,
        TokenImpersonationLevel,
        TokenStatistics,
        TokenRestrictedSids,
        TokenSessionId,
        TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
        TokenSessionReference,
        TokenSandBoxInert,
        TokenAuditPolicy,
        TokenOrigin,
        TokenElevationType,
        TokenLinkedToken,
        TokenElevation,
        TokenHasRestrictions,
        TokenAccessInformation,
        TokenVirtualizationAllowed,
        TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
        TokenIntegrityLevel,
        TokenUIAccess,
        TokenMandatoryPolicy,
        TokenLogonSid,
        TokenIsAppContainer,
        TokenCapabilities,
        TokenAppContainerSid,
        TokenAppContainerNumber,
        TokenUserClaimAttributes,
        TokenDeviceClaimAttributes,
        TokenRestrictedUserClaimAttributes,
        TokenRestrictedDeviceClaimAttributes,
        TokenDeviceGroups,
        TokenRestrictedDeviceGroups,
        TokenSecurityAttributes,
        TokenIsRestricted,
        TokenProcessTrustLevel,
        TokenPrivateNameSpace,
        TokenSingletonAttributes,
        TokenBnoIsolation,
        TokenChildProcessFlags,
        TokenIsLessPrivilegedAppContainer,
        TokenIsSandboxed,
        TokenIsAppSilo,
        MaxTokenInfoClass
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass, IntPtr TokenInformation, long TokenInformationLength, ref long ReturnLength);

    //GetTokenInformation Ends Here

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeName(
   string lpSystemName,
   IntPtr lpLuid,
   [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lpName,
   ref long cchName);

    public static void Main()
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
        IntPtr TokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        OpenProcessToken(hwnd, TOKEN_READ, ref TokenHandle);

        long ReturnLength = 0;
        GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenPrivileges, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref ReturnLength);

        IntPtr elevationptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(64);
        long TokenInformationLength = 64;
        GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenPrivileges, elevationptr, TokenInformationLength, ref TokenInformationLength);
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES)Marshal.PtrToStructure(elevationptr, typeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES));

        IntPtr startingptr = new IntPtr(elevationptr.ToInt64() + sizeof(uint));

        for (int i = 0; i < tp.PrivilegeCount; i++)
        {
            IntPtr tempptr = new IntPtr(startingptr.ToInt64() + i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES)));
            LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES laa = (LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tempptr, typeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES));
            IntPtr luidptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(laa.Luid));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(laa.Luid, luidptr, true);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
            long cchname = 50;
            // Console.WriteLine("[1]LUIDPTR: {0}", luidptr);
            LookupPrivilegeName(null, luidptr, sb, ref cchname);
            //Console.WriteLine("[2]cchname: {0}", cchname);
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(luidptr);
         
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

}

Although the "tp.PrivilegeCount" is **5**, the program crashes at the **third** loop.

By debugging with a breakpoint it was discovered that LookupPrivilegeName is trying to access the "luidptr" memory address but getting blocked with the error below -

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

It's clearly a memory allocation issue, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Edit: **I've updated the code** the program works on X64 arch, but once every few attempts it crashes/prints all privileges/does not print anything.

Comment: `public static void StructureToPtr (object structure, IntPtr ptr, bool fDeleteOld);` Are you sure you want to deleteOld? Are you the owner of it?

Comment: The point of calling GetTokenInformation twice is to first find out how much memory you need to allocate.  Which you get back in ReturnLength on the first call, it therefore must be Marshal.AllocHGlobal(ReturnLength)

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, but that's not exactly what I'm doing in the line of "IntPtr elevationptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ReturnLength));" ?

Comment: No, Marshal.SizeOf() will return 4, the size of an uint.  Not nearly big enough, thus the kaboom.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant . ReturnLength variable returns 64 bytes and I've updated it manually by changing - IntPtr elevationptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(64). but I'm still getting the same error when running on an x64 bit arch. 
By debugging it once again, it seems that it prints successfully 3 of the privileges with the following PTR addresses - 

2522253672848
SeShutdownPrivilege
2522253672576
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
2522253672448
SeUndockPrivilege

when the program gets to the fourth loop in the PTR address of 2522253672720, it crashes with an access violation.

Comment: More bugs.  The LookupPrivilegeName() declaration is wrong, last parameter is int, not long.  The StringBuilder is not large enough to store the string, use new StringBuilder(cchname)

Comment: Thank you once again @HansPassant. I have changed the declaration of LookupPrivilegeName "cchname" from ref int to ref long. but as far as I understood, new StringBuilder accepts only INT, not LONG. VS suggests type casting and I'm guessing it's not the expected behavior.

Comment: I implicitly assumed you would figure out that you have to change the cchname variable to int as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for bringing it to my attention, but I've already changed it. it seems that StringBuilder accepts only INT. please notice the following example [link](https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/SyhqEmk2TJqASbKkn89WKw.png)

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the code. could you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `SizeParamIndex` for the `StringBuilder`. You can pass `lpLuid` as an `in` parameter

- `cchName` should be `ref int`.
- Use `SafeProcessHandle` for `OpenProcessToken`.
- There is a distinct lack of error handling. You need `using` and `try` `finally` everywhere, as well as throwing `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` where necesary.
- You are leaking a lot of HGlobal memory, you need to free it.
- Instead of `64` use `ReturnLength`
- The whole `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES` struct is a waste of time, as it is dynamically sized. Since you are manually marshalling it, you may as well use `ReadInt32`.
- Use the generic form of `PtrToStructure`.

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, UInt32 DesiredAccess, out SafeProcessHandle TokenHandle);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeName(
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpSystemName,
   in LUID lpLuid,
   [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeParamIndex = 3)] StringBuilder lpName,
   ref int cchName);
```

Here is the updated code:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
    SafeProcessHandle TokenHandle;
    OpenProcessToken(hwnd, TOKEN_READ, out TokenHandle);
    if(TokenHandle.IsInvalid)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    using(TokenHandle)
    {
        if(!GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenPrivileges, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out var ReturnLength))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        IntPtr elevationptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            elevationptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(ReturnLength);
            if(!GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenPrivileges, elevationptr, ReturnLength, out var ReturnLength))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            var startingptr = new IntPtr(elevationptr.ToInt64() + sizeof(uint));
            var count = Marshal.ReadInt32(elevationptr);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var tempptr = new IntPtr(startingptr.ToInt64() + i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES)));
                var laa = Marshal.PtrToStructure<LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES>(tempptr);
                var sb = new StringBuilder(50);
                int cchname = sb.Length;
                // Console.WriteLine("[1]LUIDPTR: {0}", luidptr);
                if(!LookupPrivilegeName(null, in luidptr, sb, ref cchname))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                //Console.WriteLine("[2]cchname: {0}", cchname);
                Console.WriteLine(sb);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(elevationptr);
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```